# Infinite loop in React

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop

```
function QuestionAns(){
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [currData, setCurrData] = useState([])
    let i = 1

    useEffect(() => {
        let result = []
        const fetchFromUrl = async() => {
            const response = await axios.get(url)
            const response_data = await response.data.data
            await setData(response_data)
        }

        fetchFromUrl()
    }, [])

    const run_loop = async ()=>{
        let arr = []

        for(let counter = 0; counter < 12; counter++){
            arr.push(<Pretty count={i} question={data[i].question} answer_option={data[i].option_arr} answer={data[i].answer} key={data[i]._id} corr_ans={data[i]._id}/>)
            i+=1
        }

        let dat = await arr.concat(currData)
        await setCurrData(dat)
    }

    if(data.length){
        run_loop()
    }

    return (
        <div className="container my-3">
            <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 g-5">
                {data.length ? currData : `loading`}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default QuestionAns;
```

In this function fetchFromUrl we are getting the data from the server which is stored in the data state again I am taking 12 data from the fetched content and storing it to currData. Purpose is to make a infinite scroll. but if I keep the code like that I am getting a infinite entries of 12 data means 1 to 12 -> 1 to 12 -> 1 to 12 ..... . Problem lies with currData.

Any idea why I am getting in this infinite loop. I am good with raw js and can do this this easily but I am learning react now so any help will be appriciated.

[image: Problem screenshot]

I was expecting the data from 1-12 will load single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(data.length){
    run_loop()
}
```

this `condition` is always `true` expect for the first render before running `useEffect` but once `fetchFromUrl()` is executed  `data.length` become `true` forever since inside this `function` you are updating the useState hook

```
setData(response_data)
```

`if(data.length)` returns `true` if `data.length > 0` which is always the case unless `response.data.data` is an empty `array`

after what happens ? `run_loop()` executes and updates `currData`

```
setCurrData(dat)
```

and this will re-render the component and since `if(data.length)`is always `true` this will happen infinitely.

so I guess you are getting an infinite render not an infinite loop. try to `console.log` from inside your `jsx` to be sure

```
return (
  <div className="container my-3">
  {console.log('this is a new render')}
     <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 g-5">
       {data.length ? currData : `loading`}
     </div>
   </div>
)
```

what you should do is to make `run_loop()` part of `fetchFromUrl` so it runs inside `useEffect` I don't understand but this is what your code is doing `if(data.legth){run_loop()}`

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let result = [];
        let arr = []
        const fetchFromUrl = async() => {
            const response = await axios.get(url)
            const response_data = response.data.data
            setData(response_data)
            if(response_data.length > 11){ // this is better
              for(let counter = 0; counter < 12; counter++){
                arr.push(<Pretty count={i} question={response_data[i].question} answer_option={response_data[i].option_arr} answer={response_data[i].answer} key={response_data[i]._id} corr_ans={response_data[i]._id}/>)
                i+=1
                }
              let dat = arr.concat(currData)
              setCurrData(prevState => {
              if(prevState.length === dat.length) {return prevState} else {return dat} // this will avoid the infinite render
              })
            }
        }
        fetchFromUrl()
    }, [])
```

**NOTE ALSO** : you need the `await` key only in this line

```
const response = await axios.get(url)
```